# Display Time Interval in Minutes - Kendo Scheduler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-scheduler

How to enable/set Kendo Scheduler Display Time interval in `Minutes`. As of now its displayed in `Hours`. Like `7.00 AM , 8.00 AM`

I need to make it displayed like Below:

7.00 AM
...
7.15 AM
...
7.30 AM
...
7.45 AM
...
8.00 AM

So far i have tried:

```
$("#scheduler").kendoScheduler({
       ...
       minutesPerRow:15,
       ...
});
```

Where its not getting worked.

How to set the row interval display time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found answer my self.

I need to set **`majorTick: 15`** instead of minutesPerRow. Under the Views attribute of kendo scheduler.

```
views: [{ type: "day", selected: true, majorTick: 15 }],
```

Take a look at the [**Kendo Scheduler Configuration & Fields & Methods & Events**](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/scheduler)